# Password field being changed to text on live system

Tags: asp.net, passwords

This problem's pretty simple- we have a "Change Password" screen, and on it, the password fields are being converted to text when it's published, so when you type in it, it shows normal text, rather than the dots you'd normally get. The problem doesn't happen on my local machine when I debug it, it only happens when it's been deployed to an external server. Others have tried it too, and find the same thing. We're stumped as to why it's happening, and I've found no solutions online.

As an example, one of the textboxes is defined in markup like so (I got rid of the opening < to stop it trying to use it as HTML here):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="uxCurrentPW" type="password" runat="server" CssClass="fullWidthTextBox spaced" autocomplete="off" />
```

No server-side or javascript code is affecting it.

Comment: Just tried it in IE (was using Firefox before) and the issue is still there. Also, forgot to mention, it works on the login screen- it's just that page, for changing passwords, that has the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To Set a TextBox Web Server Control for Password Entry: Set the
>   TextBox control's TextMode property to Password.

The following:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="uxCurrentPW" TextMode="Password" runat="server" CssClass="fullWidthTextBox spaced" autocomplete="off" />
```

(**[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsfss7t0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**)